# How to install WP alongside my existing site at a sub-directory (bradydjohnson.com/blog)?

Tags: installation

I am interested in using Wordpress to run a blog on my website. I've done some research, but I can't find clear answers how to install WP to work alongside/in addition to my webpage. Any suggestions for this? How can I do this?

Website: [bradydjohnson.com](http://bradydjohnson.com)

I'd like to have a WordPress blog a bradydjohnson.com/blog

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more specific about the issues you encountered? Have you tried the following?

1. Creating a database for WordPress (if you haven't yet).
2. Copy the WordPress core files into bradydjohnson.com/blog.
3. Load bradydjohnson.com/blog on your browser to run the WordPress installation.